Has anyone been successful in sending group messaging on Whatsapp using Twilio
I am building for a use case that create and sends messages to a Whatsapp Group. It appears that Whatsapp does not support this natively, though i found this from Twilio that claims to be enabling this use case. Has anyone been able to successfully test this?
In my tests the group participants get the welcome message to join the group when i hit the createConversation.js on browser, however there is no CTA to join the group.

Thank you for reaching out about your issue with sending group messages on WhatsApp via Twilio.
It is important to clarify that the feature in question does not facilitate the creation of native WhatsApp groups, nor does it allow for direct interaction with them. Instead, Twilio has devised a group-like concept within its own systems, and the messages sent via this method are individual messages to each WhatsApp user, not group messages.
An easy way to conceptualize this is likening it to an email distribution list. When you send an email to a distribution list, you're not creating a chat room where everyone can interact simultaneously, but rather sending individual emails to each address on that list. Twilio's WhatsApp 'group messaging' works on a similar principle.

Thanks for the clarification. I am trying to build for a use case where a group message thread can be created for users (say within a Family) and we are able to send messages to this group and enable conversation within the group. Is there an API/ Product of Twilio that can help build this use case?

If you are looking for a WhatsApp-native group, no, I'm afraid there is no such API at the moment. But you should be able to use that Twilio Conversations group feature you linked above. It will just be a different experience since each family members only has one conversation with the Twilio number (and this conversation will list all the message of all family members)
